# Docker compose build after service is up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a service `web` and a service `ipfs` which runs my web app and the ipfs server, the problem is, I need `ipfs` to be up before I can build `web`. This is the docker compose I have so far:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - IPFS_ADDR=/dns/ipfs/tcp/5001
      - PIN_DATA=False
    depends_on:
      - ipfs

  ipfs:
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:v0.7.0
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
      - "5001:5001"
      - "8080:8080"
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN python ./wait_ipfs.py
RUN python -m unittest

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

And this is the content of `wait_ipfs.py`

```
from time import sleep
from ipfshttpclient.exceptions import ConnectionError

import ipfshttpclient
import sys


IPFS_ADDR = "/dns/ipfs/tcp/5001"
CID = "QmdMxMx29KVYhHnaCc1icWYxQqXwUNCae6t1wS2NqruiHd"

while True:
    try:
        with ipfshttpclient.connect(IPFS_ADDR) as client:
            data = client.get(CID)    
        break

    except ConnectionError as e:
        sleep(5)
```

The problem is, docker compose is building `web` before running `ipfs`, and since that is happening I am never able to connect and never able to finish the build. Is there a way I can get `ipfs` to run before I build `web`?

Comment: Would your image still work if you deleted the two `RUN python ...` lines?  What would happen if you `docker push`ed the built image to a repository and ran the same image on a different host with the same Compose setup?

Comment: (In general, image builds can never connect to other containers, and Compose doesn't have the notion of an image build depending on anything else.)

Comment: Yes, it would, is just that I wanted to run the tests before building, but the only thing keeping me from building the project is that the tests have to connect to the ipfs to make sure they work. Maybe I should put the tests somewhere else?